# Change the rows with the same cell value in the same color in HTML table - Django project

Tags: html, django, list, dataframe, datatable

I created a table in my html file for my Django project, and the raw data is based on the following list (It's a very long list, so I only list a few lines):

```
mylist=
[{'StartDate': '2021-10-02', 'ID': 11773, 'Receiver': Mike, 'Days':66 },
{'StartDate': '2021-10-03', 'ID': 15673, 'Receiver': Jane, 'Days':65}, 
... 
{'StartDate': '2021-10-5', 'ID': 34653, 'Receiver': Jack, 'Days':63}]
```

My Html file:

```
  <table class="table table-striped" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                                    
     <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>StartDate</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Days</th>
        
     </thead>
     <body>

{% for element in mylist %}

      <tr>
        <td>{{ element.StartDate}}</td>
        <td>{{ element.ID }}</td>
        <td>{{ element.Receiver }}</td>
        <td>{{ element.Days }}</td>

       </tr>
      {% endfor %}      
       </tbody>
                         
      </table>
```

I want to make all the rows with the same ID value the same color. Please advise what I should add into the `<td>{{ element.ID }}</td>`. Thank you!

parts of my views.py:

```
client = gspread.service_account_from_dict(creds)


def CreateSheet(Return_record):
    sheet = client.open(Return_record).sheet1
    return sheet

from sheet2api import Sheet2APIClient


sheet = client.open('Return Record 2022')
sheet_instance = sheet.get_worksheet(0)
mylist = sheet_instance.get_all_records()
mylist


def table2022(request):
    return render(request,'table2022.html',{'mylist':mylist})
```

Comment: Do you want to set a unique color to every unique `ID` cell? If there are many `ID`'s, there will be a lot of colors.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Unique color will be better, but It will be ok if some of the IDs share the same color because I just want my table to be clear. Is that possible to set a color list, and they will pick the color in that list? "mylist" is dynamic data from my google sheet

Comment: Or maybe I can make all the IDs that end with 1 to red, 2 to green... but I don't know how to do this either.

Comment: 10 colors is more reasonable idea. In that case, could you please share your `views.py` in question?

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. I already added my views.py in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything we want to pass as context, we should keep inside `view` we want to use it in. It's more readable when we have more and more code.

What we are going to do, it's define a color for numbers 0-9. I'll pick some light `colors` for now, you can change them as you prefer.

views.py:

```
def table2022(request):
    mylist = sheet_instance.get_all_records()
    colors = {'0': 'aqua', '1': 'beige', '2': 'burlywood', '3': 'lightgrey', '4': 'silver', '5': 'skyblue', '6': 'lightblue', '7': 'lightpink', '8': 'lightgreen', '9': 'lawngreen'}
    context = {'mylist': mylist, 'colors': colors}

    return render(request, 'table2022.html', context)
```

Now, because in templates it's not that simple to use `Python`, we need to create custom `Template Tag`. Let's start with creating folder in your app, let's name it `custom_tags.py`. It should be created in `YourProject/your_app/templatetags/` folder, so we have to also create `templatetags` folder in there.

custom_tags.py:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='get_color')
def get_color(colors, number):
    return colors[str(number)[-1]]
```

your_template.html:

```
{% load custom_tags %}

...

{% for element in mylist %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ element.StartDate }}</td>
        <td style="background-color: {{ colors|get_color:element.ID }}">
            {{ element.ID }}
        </td>
        <td>{{ element.Receiver }}</td>
        <td>{{ element.Days }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

`get_color` tag is basically taking whole `ID`, then extract only last number and make it a string. After that it uses the single number as a key in `colors` dictionary and passes corresponding value to template, where it is going to be a valid html color.

Custom tags are used to 'implement' some Pythonic code directly into template. Don't use it too much, because most of coding should be in standard files like `views.py` and `models.py`. But sometimes there is no better way. :)

For more details about `Tags`, check that [Django's DOCS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters)

Comment: I've edited post few minutes after creation. Check `custom_tags.py` file again please :)

Comment: It works!! Thank you so much!

Comment: Enjoy! Stay creative, `custom_tags` will help you with that :)

Comment: OMG, you are so awesome. Thank you!!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again! If I want to set the color based on the last 2 dits, should I go colors = {'00': 'aqua', '01': 'beige', '02': 'burlywood', '03': 'violet', '04': 'silver', '05': 'skyblue', '06': 'lightblue', '07': 'lightpink' ...... '98': 'lavender', '99': 'indigo'}    and keep the custom_tags.py unchanged? Thank you!!

Comment: You need to slightly modify outcome to `return colors[str(number)[-2:]]`

Comment: You're awesome!!  May I please ask you an extended python question? If I want to select, for example, the 4th and 5th digits, what should I change in `colors[str(number)[-1]]` ?

Comment: @MaryMa - it's really basic string as list indexing. Read about it i.e. here: https://railsware.com/blog/python-for-machine-learning-indexing-and-slicing-for-lists-tuples-strings-and-other-sequential-types/

Comment: Can you help me with this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71117001/adding-list-data-in-a-javascript-line-chart-django-project