# Adding list data in a JavaScript line chart - Django project

Tags: javascript, python, django, charts

I created a list and defined it in my `views.py`:

```
mydata = [{'date': '2020-01-02T00:00:00Z', 'value': 13}, 
{'date': '2020-01-03T00:00:00Z', 'value': 2}, 
{'date': '2020-01-06T00:00:00Z', 'value': 5}]
```

I want to add my own data in a template js chart in my HTML file:

```
<script>
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);
chart.paddingRight = 20;

var data = [];
var visits = 10;
for (var i = 1; i < 50000; i++) {
  visits += Math.round((Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1) * Math.random() * 10);
       data.push({
           date: new Date(2018, 0, i),
            value: visits
            });
      }

chart.data = data;

var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
dateAxis.minZoomCount = 5;

dateAxis.groupData = true;
dateAxis.groupCount = 500;

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
series.tooltipText = "{valueY}";
series.tooltip.pointerOrientation = "vertical";
series.tooltip.background.fillOpacity = 0.5;

chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.cursor.xAxis = dateAxis;

var scrollbarX = new am4core.Scrollbar();
scrollbarX.marginBottom = 20;
chart.scrollbarX = scrollbarX;

var selector = new am4plugins_rangeSelector.DateAxisRangeSelector();
selector.container = document.getElementById("selectordiv");
selector.axis = dateAxis; 
  </script>
```

I know I should change the `chart.data = data`, but when I replaced it with `chart.data = {{mydata}}`, the chart didn't display anything. I tried change it manually: `chart.data = [{'date': '2020-01-02T00:00:00Z', 'value': 13},  {'date': '2020-01-03T00:00:00Z', 'value': 2},  {'date': '2020-01-06T00:00:00Z', 'value': 5}]` and the data was displayed successfully.

I'm sure I imported `mydata` correctly in `views.py`, because I tested `{{mydata}}` in the HTML file, it showed the whole list. I also tried `chart.data = {mydata}`, `chart.data = mydata` and `chart.data = [mydata]`, but none of them worked.

Comment: You probably forgot JSON-encoding the data.

Comment: But when I tested `{{mydata}}` in the HTML file, the whole list would show up, which means  the data has been imported

Comment: Did you try it with `{{ mydata | escapejs }}` ?  You might want to even try JSON.parse on the `chart.data`, oh and also in the views.py send the data converted to a json string `json.dumps(mydata)` and send that through the response context, not the raw dict

Comment: Thank you. I tried `{{ mydata | escapejs }}` but it still didn't work. I also tried `mydata=json.dumps(mydata)` in my views.py, and it also didn't work. I think you are right, it should be a parsing issue. Could you please advise me more on this?

Comment: `chart.data = JSON.parse({{mydata}})` also doesn't work.     If I enter `{{ mydata | escapejs }}` and `JSON.parse({{mydata}})` in my html, the whole list sill be displayed, but they just cannot be linked to the `chart.data =`

Comment: The thing is the raw list can be displayed in the chart if I manually paste it in `chart.data =`. And the list can be shown up in the HTML if I test it within a {{  }} . What did I miss??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by myself.

In the chart area, I simply used:

```
chart.data = {{ mydata | safe }}
```